# Вызов функции 1С из delphi

Tags: delphi, 1с, com, ole

Недавно наткнулся на проблему с 1С Предприятием.

Нужно вызвать функцию из общего модуля базы данных. На сколько я понимаю, общий модуль БД должен быть глобальным, серверным, а сами функции с припиской "Экспорт" (Если я что-то неправильно говорю, то поправьте, т.к. с 1С я ни разу не работал до этого).

Дёргать функцию из БазыДанных должна программка на Delphi. Коннект производится через COM соединение (Вроде бы COM должен для таких целей служить).

```
function Connect_To_1C(OLE_SERVER_TYPE, InitLine: string): Variant;
begin
  Result := Unassigned;
  OLE_SERVER_TYPE := Trim(OLE_SERVER_TYPE);
  if Length(OLE_SERVER_TYPE) <= 0 then OLE_SERVER_TYPE := 'V83.COMConnector';
  InitLine := Trim(InitLine);
  if Length(OLE_SERVER_TYPE) > 0 then begin
     Result := CreateOleObject(OLE_SERVER_TYPE);
     Result := Result.Connect(InitLine);
     if Connect_status(Result) then begin
       ShowMessage('Connect success');
     end else
     begin
       ShowMessage('Connect faled');
     end;
  end;
end;
```

Вот функция, которая производит коннект к базе. "Вроде работает - и так сойдёт". Ну вот, теперь у меня есть объект с которым можно работать (Обзовём его COM_obj).

Теперь по базе: В ней содержится простенькая функция ПРИВЕТСТВИЕ, которая выводит на экран "hello world" и возвращает значение 1. Так вот, как мне вызвать эту функцию из Delphi?? `COM_obj.ПРИВЕТСТВИЕ('')` - выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Какого типа переменная `COM_obj`?

Comment: Переменная COM_obj имеет тип Variant (пробовал и с OleVariant)

Comment: OleVariant будет работать (если такая функция есть)

Comment: OleVariant то работает, но при обращении к функции/процедуре в виде COM_obj.Приветствие(); выдаёт ошибку, что метод не поддерживается авто объектом

Comment: Боже мой!!!
У всех нас бывают плохи дни, когда ищешь ошибку в коде целый день...
Так вот. При использовании COM_obj : OleVariant можно вызвать метод из общего модуля. Конструкция OLE_obj.Проба.Приветствие(''); сработала. Ошибка заключалась в том, что я думал что эта функция (Приветствие) глобальная - т.е. обращаться можно напрямую. Но про путь к ней я совсем забыл (она весит в модуле Проба).
Спасибо вам, Антон, что сказали "будет работать". Это заставило меня с самого начала пересмотреть код.
Вопрос Закрыт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная `COM_obj` должна быть типа `OleVariant`. Тогда вызов

```
COM_obj.ПРИВЕТСТВИЕ('')
```

будет работать. При условии, что функция `ПРИВЕТСТВИЕ()` существует